# Snakemake: Hiding certain rules from DAG visualisation

Tags: python, grep, bioinformatics, snakemake, dot

In my snakemake pipeline, I have an 'all' rule, which located at the very bottom of the DAG of jobs. It's essentially the entry point for snakemake, but it doesn't do anything other than list all of the desired outputs.

Is there a way to hide this rule from the DAG visualization?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `snakemake --dag` generates a `dot` graph that can be modified as needed. For example:

```sh
snakemake --dag > test.dot
# edit test.dot to remove node 0 and all edges linking it
dot -Tpng test.dot -o test.png
```

In principle, editing of the `dot` file can also be automated using `grep`/`sed`/`awk`:

```sh
snakemake --dag | grep -v "> 0\|0\[label" | dot -Tpng -o test.png
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to add on to your response, I made the grep more specific to just the all rule by doing: `grep -v "\-> 0\|0\[label = \"all\""`