# Specify a color for each rule in Snakemake DAG

Tags: python, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs, dot

I'm running `snakemake -n -c1 --dag | dot -Tsvg > dag.svg` to get the DAG file.
I was wondering if I could somehow set the color scheme for every node. For example, in the picture below, rule `samtools_fixmate` is of different color from `samtools_sort` and of `samtools_markduplicates`. Can you somehow specify within snakemake file what color the nodes should be?

I'll settle even for out-of-snakefile solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966850/10693596), you can export the dag into a dot file:

```sh
snakemake --dag > test.dot
```

The dot file can then be edited as necessary.