# Deterministic colors for Snakemake --dag/--rulegraph output

Tags: snakemake

When I run `snakemake --dag` or `snakemake --rulegraph` multiple times on the same workflow, I get an identical layout but different, apparently random, colors. Is there a way I can provide a seed to get deterministic behavior?

> **Background**: For one of my workflows, I use a git pre-commit hook to auto-generate a plot of the workflow diagram. This is convenient, as updates to the workflow are automatically handled. But because Snakemake generates random colors each time, the  diagram graphic file is updated essentially every commit even when no changes have been made to the workflow. I'm contemplating possible ways to update the graphic only when the workflow structure has changed.

Comment: This hack might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71752335/10693596 Having what you describe as a built-in feature would be nice.